# WCF Contracts and Models in a MVVM client

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, mvvm

I have a WCF service, and a WPF client application, built using the MVVM Pattern. The referenced WCF service allows the WPF client to manipulate contracts which describes the data that can be sent and received from the service.

Exemple Contract, defined Service side :

```
[DataContract()]
public class UserContract : BaseContract
{
    [DataMember()]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember()]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

If I consider those referenced contracts as part of the Model Tier of my MVVM application, what should be the relationship between this contracts, and the model classes of my Model Tier ? (Code examples on client side)

**1. Inheritance ?** Models inherits contracts.

```
public class UserModel : UserContract
```

**2. Composition ?** Models hold an instance of the corresponding contract.

```
public class UserModel
{
  public UserContract userContract {get;set;}
}
```

**3. Addition ?** Contracts being declared Partial, I could just "complete" contracts, and use them directly as my model classes.

```
public partial class UserContract
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you should keep your `Model Layer` separate from `Contract Layer`. I feel contracts should act like `DTOs` or `Messages` between application and service and that is it.

--EDIT--

- `Model Layer/Business Layer`: Composed of `Business Logic` and `Business Rules`.
- `Contract Layer` : Composed of `Models` and other information needed to send/receive data correctly.

Example :

[This example uses Request/Response pattern.]

Model:

```
public class User
{
    public String Username { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

Contracts:

```
public class GetUsersRequest
{ }

public class GetUsersResponse
{
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsSuccess { get; set; }
}
```

Service:

```
public interface IUserService
{
    GetUsersResponse GetUsers(GetUsersRequest request);
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public GetUsersResponse GetUsers(GetUsersRequest request)
    {
        GetUsersResponse response = new GetUsersResponse();
        //...
        return response;
    }
}
```

If you see here, Contract `GetUsersResponse` is composed of `List of Users`. It is used to transfer `Users` from `Service` to `Client`.

On the other hand, `Model Layer` does not know anything about `Contract Layer`. That is important. `Business Entities` should not know anything about other Layers. There should always be classes in `Business Layer` that populate these entities from `Data Layer`.

Comment: @decyclone : You mean a fourth option : Separation - Contract are used to build model on receivings, Models are used to build contracts on sendings, through other objects (Repositories / Factories) with no link kept during other tasks ?

Comment: @decyclone : Considering your edits, you suggest to entirely keep the Model Layer on the service side, being "sealed" for the client side ?

Comment: No, it should be is an assembly shared both by service and client.

Comment: @decyclone : wow I didnt know you could reference data without using a DataContract. Is there any drawbacks to this way of encapsulating data ? All wcf examples I`ve seen so far were using DataContract to send their data. What happens if you reference models in models ? Or do you keep a "reference by Id" way for the model layer to have the models as light as possible ? Sorry if that`s a lot of a questions, but your answers open a lot of new interesting doors for me :)

Comment: Hey, I did not included `DataContract` tags on Request/Response classes. And I have also not marked IUserService with `ServiceContract` and `OperationContract`. I hope you are very clear on this and just wanted to discuss on your doubts on architecture.

Comment: @decyclone : Yes, I did a test project based on your answer and was surprised to find this : [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()] private ModelTier.User[] UsersField; in my service reference. I will continue to research about that, and maybe come back with some new questions, Thanks :)